# In WPF, is it possible to set the binding of a property to a binding dependency property?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am looking to bind a textbox dynamically - updating the binding when the property in the code behind changes... Is there a way to set a property to bind using a binding in the code behind using XAML?

In the code behind:

```
...
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

        }

 public Binding CurrentBinding
    {
        get { return (Binding)GetValue(CurrentBindingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentBindingProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentBinding.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentBinding", typeof(Binding), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
...
```

In the XAML:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentBinding}"/>
```

Obviously this isn't working - I presume since a binding can't be used in another binding.  Any other possible solutions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but what you could do is change the Binding when your other Binding change. If you give more information about what you are trying to do, I could give an exemple.

Comment: There are lots of ways to approach your problem, including just providing a bindable property in your view model that reacts to the original source property in the way you want. Your question is too broad, because it lacks any specifics about what you tried, or even an example of exactly what it is you're trying to do. Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: An alternative might be to use a `Style` with `DataTrigger`s. `DataTrigger`s can change a property's binding based on the value of another binding.

Comment: @qscott: Why don't you change the *value*  of the source property instead of trying to change the actual binding?